# How to lock /check if locked linux file in python

Tags: python, linux

I need to implement the following functionality

```
locked = False
while not locked:
    file_path = get_file_path_from_poll()
    locked = try_lock_file(file_path)
    if locked:
       # do some staff
       locked = True
       release_lock(file_path)
```

How can this be implemented in python?
I need to work with Linux files, cause there will be many different processes and each should lock one of the files from some folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linux+flock+%5Bpython%5D. Your loop doesn't make much sense, btw. If `locked` is true, you set it to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are very simplistic examples of using `fcntl`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#module-fcntl

The first uses `LOCK_NB` to avoid blocking, the second doesn't, which means it will block, waiting for file access.

```
import fcntl
import time
print('Attempting to lock file')
f = open('./locked.txt', 'w')
fcntl.flock(f.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
print ('Lock Acquired')
f.write("some text")

print('Attempting 2nd lock')
f2 = open('./locked.txt', 'r')
f2_locked = False
try:
    fcntl.flock(f2.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX|fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except BlockingIOError:
    print ('The file is Locked 2')
    f2_locked = True

print('Sleeping with file locked')
print('Run this program from another terminal to test')
time.sleep(15)
print('File closed try again')
f.close()
time.sleep(15)
```

This example blocks, waiting for file access

```
import fcntl
import time
print('Attempting to lock file')
f = open('./locked.txt', 'w')
fcntl.flock(f.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX)
print ('Lock Acquired')
f.write("some text 2")

print('Sleeping with file locked')
print('Run this program from another terminal to test')
time.sleep(15)
print('File closed try again')
f.close()
time.sleep(15)
```